# AppStore Submission: Query about Universal App

Tags: ipad, app-store, universal

I have recently created a Universal App in Xcode 4 to build my new app. I have completed the iPad component only and intend to submit it to the app store.

My question is, do I need to create a new iPad specific app for the submission or can I submit the universal app (without the iPhone component) with some tweaks?

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

Zhen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Universal app should support both platforms. If you do not have any views or code specifically for the iPhone, then you should just submit it as an iPad app. And if later you decide to add iPhone specific features, you can do so and submit an update as a universal app.

Submitting a `Universal` app that does not have any iPhone specific views or features could possibly get your app rejected.

You can always submit updates when you have both platform specific features working.

Comment: @WrightCS, so this means I need to create an iPad Specific app from scratch and copy the code there ya?

Comment: You can just change the **Devices** to iPad, instead of Universal.